# Excel Coding Question Updating Date on Sheet

Tags: excel

I am making a program in python which will help a vineyard manager manage their sprays dates currently this is the code I have for the button. I was wondering on how I would make this code update depending on the date for example when I launch up the sheet tomorrow I want the days since spray value to be updated.

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim fertilizerType As String
Dim vineyardName As String
Dim currentDate As Date
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Dim targetRange As Range

```
' Prompt user for vineyard name
vineyardName = Application.InputBox("Enter the vineyard name:", "Vineyard Name Prompt", Type:=2)

' Prompt user for fertilizer type
fertilizerType = Application.InputBox("Enter the fertilizer type:", "Fertilizer Type Prompt", Type:=2)

' Prompt user for date or use today's date
Dim dateChoice As Integer
dateChoice = MsgBox("Do you want to pick a specific date?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Date Selection")

If dateChoice = vbYes Then
    Dim selectedDate As String
    selectedDate = Application.InputBox("Enter the date (format: dd/mm/yyyy):", "Date Selection", Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy"), Type:=2)
    
    If selectedDate = "" Then
        currentDate = Date
    Else
        On Error Resume Next
        currentDate = DateValue(selectedDate)
        
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            MsgBox "Invalid date format. Today's date will be used instead."
            currentDate = Date
            Err.Clear
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
Else
    currentDate = Date
End If

' Format currentDate as "year/date/month" if today's date is used
If currentDate = Date Then
    currentDate = Format(currentDate, "yyyy/dd/mm")
End If

' Specify the target sheet where the values will be recorded
Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Modify as needed

' Find the next available row in column A
Set targetRange = targetSheet.Range("A" & targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1)

' Write vineyard name in target cell
targetRange.Value = vineyardName

' Write fertilizer type in the cell next to it
targetRange.Offset(0, 1).Value = fertilizerType

' Write current date in the cell next to the fertilizer type
targetRange.Offset(0, 2).Value = Format(currentDate, "yyyy/dd/mm")

Dim lastSprayDate As Date
Dim daysSinceSpray As Integer

' Calculate and write the number of days since last spray for vineyard "Ted"
If vineyardName = "Ted" Then
    ' Find the last spray date in column C (assuming the dates are in column C)
    lastSprayDate = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Value
    
    ' Calculate the number of days since the last spray
    daysSinceSpray = DateDiff("d", lastSprayDate, Date)
    
    ' Write the number of days since the last spray in cell B2
    targetSheet.Range("B2").Value = "Ted vineyard days since spray: " & daysSinceSpray
End If

' Calculate and write the number of days since last spray for vineyard "Oliver Hwy"
If vineyardName = "Oliver Hwy" Then
    ' Find the last spray date in column C (assuming the dates are in column C)
    lastSprayDate = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Value
    
    ' Calculate the number of days since the last spray
    daysSinceSpray = DateDiff("d", lastSprayDate, Date)
    
    ' Write the number of days since the last spray in cell A2
    targetSheet.Range("A2").Value = "Oliver Hwy vineyard days since spray: " & daysSinceSpray
End If

' Calculate and write the number of days since last spray for vineyard "Pen"
If vineyardName = "Pen" Then
    ' Find the last spray date in column C (assuming the dates are in column C)
    lastSprayDate = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Value
    
    ' Calculate the number of days since the last spray
    daysSinceSpray = DateDiff("d", lastSprayDate, Date)
    
    ' Write the number of days since the last spray in cell C2
    targetSheet.Range("C2").Value = "Pen vineyard days since spray: " & daysSinceSpray
End If

' Calculate and write the number of days since last spray for vineyard "Tucel"
If vineyardName = "Tucel" Then
    ' Find the last spray date in column C (assuming the dates are in column C)
    lastSprayDate = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Value
    
    ' Calculate the number of days since the last spray
    daysSinceSpray = DateDiff("d", lastSprayDate, Date)
    
    ' Write the number of days since the last spray in cell A3
    targetSheet.Range("A3").Value = "Tucel vineyard days since spray: " & daysSinceSpray
End If

' Calculate and write the number of days since last spray for vineyard "Ok Fall"
If vineyardName = "Ok Fall" Then
    ' Find the last spray date in column C (assuming the dates are in column C)
    lastSprayDate = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Value
    
    ' Calculate the number of days since the last spray
    daysSinceSpray = DateDiff("d", lastSprayDate, Date)
    
    ' Write the number of days since the last spray in cell B3
    targetSheet.Range("B3").Value = "Ok Fall vineyard days since spray: " & daysSinceSpray
End If

' Calculate and write the number of days since last spray for vineyard "Rust Wine"
If vineyardName = "Rust Wine" Then
    ' Find the last spray date in column C (assuming the dates are in column C)
    lastSprayDate = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Value
    
    ' Calculate the number of days since the last spray
    daysSinceSpray = DateDiff("d", lastSprayDate, Date)
    
    ' Write the number of days since the last spray in cell C3
    targetSheet.Range("C3").Value = "Rust Wine vineyard days since spray: " & daysSinceSpray
End If

' Notify user about the recorded values
MsgBox "Vineyard: " & vineyardName & vbNewLine & "Fertilizer type: " & fertilizerType & vbNewLine & "Date recorded: " & currentDate
```

End Sub.

I tried to make the date update using the code below however this just made my sheet crash.

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Dim lastSprayDate As Date
Dim daysSinceSpray As Long ' Change the data type to Long

```
' Specify the target sheet where the values are recorded
Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Modify as needed

' Calculate and update the number of days since last spray for each vineyard

' Vineyard "Ted"
lastSprayDate = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Value
daysSinceSpray = DateDiff("d", lastSprayDate, Date)
targetSheet.Range("B2").Offset(1).Value = "Ted vineyard days since spray: " & daysSinceSpray

' Vineyard "Oliver Hwy"
lastSprayDate = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value
daysSinceSpray = DateDiff("d", lastSprayDate, Date)
targetSheet.Range("A2").Offset(1).Value = "Oliver Hwy vineyard days since spray: " & daysSinceSpray

' Vineyard "Pen"
lastSprayDate = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value
daysSinceSpray = DateDiff("d", lastSprayDate, Date)
targetSheet.Range("C2").Offset(1).Value = "Pen vineyard days since spray: " & daysSinceSpray

' Vineyard "Tucel"
lastSprayDate = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(2).Value
daysSinceSpray = DateDiff("d", lastSprayDate, Date)
targetSheet.Range("A3").Offset(1).Value = "Tucel vineyard days since spray: " & daysSinceSpray

' Vineyard "Ok Fall"
lastSprayDate = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(2).Value
daysSinceSpray = DateDiff("d", lastSprayDate, Date)
targetSheet.Range("B3").Offset(1).Value = "Ok Fall vineyard days since spray: " & daysSinceSpray

' Vineyard "Rust Wine"
lastSprayDate = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(2).Value
daysSinceSpray = DateDiff("d", lastSprayDate, Date)
targetSheet.Range("C3").Offset(1).Value = "Rust Wine vineyard days since spray: " & daysSinceSpray

' Save the workbook to persist the updated values
ThisWorkbook.Save
```

End Sub

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.